# Why is my initialisation of collection not working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a service class annotated with `@Transactional` calling a DAO layer method to return an object with a collection on it lazily loaded. When I then try and initialize this collection in the service layer using `Hibernate.inititialize(..)`, hibernate doesn't load the collection. The DAO is configured to use entity manager and the object class is annotated with JPA annotations. I have the following spring application context..

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"...">

<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource" url="..." username="..." password="..."/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Hibernate entity manager -->
<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.gmp.webapp.model" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
     </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
  class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dao" class="org.gmp.webapp.dao.impl.HibDAOImpl" />
</beans>
```

My DAO interface and implementaionn...

```
package org.gmp.webapp.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.gmp.webapp.model.Crime;

public interface DAO {
    public Crime getCrime(String crimeNo);
}

import org.gmp.webapp.dao.DAO;
import org.gmp.webapp.model.Crime;

public class HibDAOImpl implements DAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Crime getCrime(String crimeNo) {
        return this.em.find(Crime.class, crimeNo);
    }

}
```

My object looks something like this..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CRIME_TABLE")
public class Crime {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CRIME_NO")
    private String crimeNo;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="PER_CRIME_NO", referencedColumnName="CRIME_NO")
    private List<PersonCrimeLink> personLinks;
    ....
    public List<PersonCrimeLink> getPersonLinks() {
        return personLinks;
    }
}
```

The service class is annotated with transactional (spring) so I thought as the call to the DAO and the initialize were in the same transaction, this should work. 
My service..

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CrimeServiceImpl implements CrimeService {

    @Autowired private CrimeDAO crimeDAO;

    public Crime getCrime(String crimeNo) {
        Crime crime = crimeDAO.getCrime(crimeNo);
        Hibernate.initialize(crime.getPersonLinks());
        return crime;
    }
}
```

The collection is loaded when I run a test of the DAO method, when making a call to the getter for the collection. I have annotated the test method with `@Transactional`. The `personLinks` object is omitted but like I say it returns the records in the test. I think I am not understanding the transaction manager I am using as this process worked when I was using session factory and `HibernateTransactionManager`. 
Many Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip on this, as you decided to use the JPA's EntityManagerFactory instead of the Hibernate's SessionFactory as your orm API, then i would stick to that API on other layers of the application.

That is, using the EntityManager to get the data and then switch to using the implementation API (Hibernate.initialize) is not a consistent / maintainable approach.

Like you said in the post, if you stick to the JPA specification, which is initializing collection once it is accessed for the first time then you do not get any errors and the list is loaded:

> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed

So as of JPA specification, you only need to do this:

```
public Crime getCrime(String crimeNo) {
        Crime crime = crimeDAO.getCrime(crimeNo);
        crime.getPersonLinks().size(); // any access method
        return crime;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks. So I will need a separate method to retrieve the same object with its collections initialised. Is there no alternative to Hibernate.initialize. Seems like there should be.

Comment: No, you only need to access the collection is some way while still being under transactional context. Please see my updated post.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Its like the transaction is not starting in the service,.it may be my config is not right.

Comment: On Crime antity add mappedBy on the personLinks collection @OneToMany(mappedBy = "crime").

Comment: i found the old hibernate mapping file for crime entity still in my project. After removing this it seems to work. There are other hbm files present which the project is using. I don't understand why as the mapping files are not registered anywhere and I am using entity manager. I do have a persistence xml file but this does not contain mapping file details and the files are hbm anyway. Does it pick these up in a default directory? Sorry for wasting your time on previous question.

Comment: No, you have to explicitly specify your hbm.xml files with <property name="mappingResources">. You are using <property name="packagesToScan" so you only load the annotated entities

Comment: Hi. From the hibernate documentation.. "mapping-file.., Hibernate EntityManager will try to load the mapping file located in the jar file at META_INF/orm.xml. Of course any explicit mapping file will be loaded too. As a matter of fact, you can provide any XML file in the mapping file element ie. either hbm files or EJB3 deployment descriptor." .. it looks like my mapping files were being loaded although they were not explicitly registered. This would explain why my original code was not working, as it was using the old hibernate mapping file for my crime entity. Do you agree?

Comment: Agree, because i doubt this would work without the @OneToMany(mappedBy = "crime"). If this was not in the legacy hbm and this is the one which was loaded, then yes, you would not get this to work.